# Comparision of floats using awk one liner

Tags: awk

I have a file whose content is as mentioned below.

```
INFO  | L 09 Aug 2019 14:23:13.073216 | eoTcapCAP       | LinksHandler stats: Probe <100.145.223.37>. FID <549>. State <Browse>, LCS <09 Aug 2019 10:50:34.587>, new-CSDRs <5000>, CSDR/s <78>, avg-read <0.033>, avg-scan <104.494>, read-ops <5>, total_csdr <5000>,  browse-time <17.187>, browse-act <DELIVERING>
INFO  | L 09 Aug 2019 14:23:13.073548 | eoTcapCAP       | LinksHandler stats: Probe <10.124.263.71>. FID <549>. State <Browse>, LCS <09 Aug 2019 11:23:11.800>, new-CSDRs <0>, CSDR/s <0>, avg-read <2.029>, avg-scan <79.735>, read-ops <31>, total_csdr <0>,  browse-time <1.038>, browse-act <BROWSING>
INFO  | L 09 Aug 2019 14:23:13.073681 | eoTcapCAP       | LinksHandler stats: Probe <10.116.213.48>. FID <549>. State <Browse>, LCS <09 Aug 2019 11:23:11.100>, new-CSDRs <0>, CSDR/s <0>, avg-read <2.016>, avg-scan <79.713>, read-ops <31>, total_csdr <0>,  browse-time <1.791>, browse-act <BROWSING>
INFO  | L 09 Aug 2019 14:23:13.073714 | eoTcapCAP       | LinksHandler stats: Probe <10.126.223.53>. FID <549>. State <Browse>, LCS <09 Aug 2019 10:50:34.545>, new-CSDRs <413000>, CSDR/s <6353>, avg-read <0.046>, avg-scan <1.248>, read-ops <413>, total_csdr <413000>,  browse-time <2.806>, browse-act <DELIVERING>
```

I need to filter out the results where "avg-scan" is greater than 2.

I can get the average scan output with this command

```
less aa |grep "avg-scan" |head |awk  '{ print $31 }' |tr -d "<" |tr -d ">" |tr -d ","
```

I want to basically do some thing like this

```
less aa | grep "avg-scan" |head |awk  '{if ($31 >= "2") print $1}'
```

Expected output is

```
INFO  | L 09 Aug 2019 14:23:13.073216 | eoTcapCAP       | LinksHandler stats: Probe <100.145.223.37>. FID <549>. State <Browse>, LCS <09 Aug 2019 10:50:34.587>, new-CSDRs <5000>, CSDR/s <78>, avg-read <0.033>, avg-scan <104.494>, read-ops <5>, total_csdr <5000>,  browse-time <17.187>, browse-act <DELIVERING>
INFO  | L 09 Aug 2019 14:23:13.073548 | eoTcapCAP       | LinksHandler stats: Probe <10.124.263.71>. FID <549>. State <Browse>, LCS <09 Aug 2019 11:23:11.800>, new-CSDRs <0>, CSDR/s <0>, avg-read <2.029>, avg-scan <79.735>, read-ops <31>, total_csdr <0>,  browse-time <1.038>, browse-act <BROWSING>
INFO  | L 09 Aug 2019 14:23:13.073681 | eoTcapCAP       | LinksHandler stats: Probe <10.116.213.48>. FID <549>. State <Browse>, LCS <09 Aug 2019 11:23:11.100>, new-CSDRs <0>, CSDR/s <0>, avg-read <2.016>, avg-scan <79.713>, read-ops <31>, total_csdr <0>,  browse-time <1.791>, browse-act <BROWSING>
```

Answer (score 3):

I really don't understand why you use `less`, then `grep`, then `head`, then `awk`. Usually when you use `awk`, you can avoid using all the other commands.

Using `grep`, you could do :

```
grep -E "avg-scan <(1[0-9]|[2-9])" <file>
```

It searchs all the lines that contains avg-scan then a value that begins with a digit >= 2 or a value that begins with 1 + another digit (i.e a value >= 10)

I would not use awk because file is not properly delimited.

Comment: I used head since it was a big file. This was a clever solution as you don't actually need awk for this.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk  'match($0,/avg-scan[^>]*/){val=substr($0,RSTART+10,RLENGTH-10); if(val>2){print $0}}'  Input_file
```

I haven't tested it since I am traveling. If above not working try changing `RLENGTH-10` to `RLENGTH-11`.

Comment: This did not yield any output.

Comment: Please check now and let me know on same.

Comment: May you elaborate your solution. I have not come across these kind of expression before

Comment: Sure, give me few mins

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `awk`:

```
awk '{len=length($31); value=substr($31,2,len-3)+0; if (value>2)print $0 }' file.txt
```

First, Awk will find the length of the `avg-scan` value, then extract the numerical part and if it is greater than 2 then it prints the entire line.

Comment: @CorentinLimier thank you for the input (especially about casting). Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would aim to define the field separator of awk correctly to match the input format and to eliminate the extra punctuation that way, assuming the number and order of fields is constant (based on your examples, it seems to be), e.g.:

```
awk -F '([ ]+[|][ ]+)|(>[., >]+)|( <)' '$18 == "avg-scan" && $19 >= 2' aa
```

Assuming your input file name is `aa`. You can pipe the *output* to `head` and/or `less` (rather than the input, as you were doing).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple `awk` script that use `FPAT` to identified the required data fields

`script.awk`

```
BEGIN{FPAT="<[^>]*"} # store into input fields only the <> bracketed text (include leading < )
{
    avgScan = substr($8,2) + 0; # trim leading < from 8th field and convert it to number
    if (avgScan > 2) print; # if 8th fiedl > 2 print line
}
```

running :

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

or one liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="<[^>]*"}{a=substr($8,2)+0;if(a>2)print}' input.txt
```

Comment: You should mention it requires GNU awk for FPAT.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[<>]' '$16 > 2' file
INFO  | L 09 Aug 2019 14:23:13.073216 | eoTcapCAP       | LinksHandler stats: Probe <100.145.223.37>. FID <549>. State <Browse>, LCS <09 Aug 2019 10:50:34.587>, new-CSDRs <5000>, CSDR/s <78>, avg-read <0.033>, avg-scan <104.494>, read-ops <5>, total_csdr <5000>,  browse-time <17.187>, browse-act <DELIVERING>
INFO  | L 09 Aug 2019 14:23:13.073548 | eoTcapCAP       | LinksHandler stats: Probe <10.124.263.71>. FID <549>. State <Browse>, LCS <09 Aug 2019 11:23:11.800>, new-CSDRs <0>, CSDR/s <0>, avg-read <2.029>, avg-scan <79.735>, read-ops <31>, total_csdr <0>,  browse-time <1.038>, browse-act <BROWSING>
INFO  | L 09 Aug 2019 14:23:13.073681 | eoTcapCAP       | LinksHandler stats: Probe <10.116.213.48>. FID <549>. State <Browse>, LCS <09 Aug 2019 11:23:11.100>, new-CSDRs <0>, CSDR/s <0>, avg-read <2.016>, avg-scan <79.713>, read-ops <31>, total_csdr <0>,  browse-time <1.791>, browse-act <BROWSING>
```